# Android Regular expression grab an image url from a site

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching, expression

I am making an app and I have this problem
I use a patter recognition code to find the image url of an article at a site.

The problem is that in my way it grabs the first photo which is extra small.

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.*\.jpg");
There is a XL image which I would like to grab its destination.

I would like to use a pattern that at the end of the link it goes like this

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.)+(.*\[_XL]+(.jpg))");

or 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.*\_XL.jpg");

This is where I need your help 
Here is the code

public void run() {

```
        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.*\\.jpg");
        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.*\\._XL.jpg");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.)+(.*\\[_XL]+(.jpg))");

        try {
                    URL url = new URL(selectedRssItem.getLink());

                    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
                    Log.d("MIMIS_LINK", url.toString());
                    BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());

                    builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int byteRead;
                    while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1)
                        builder.append((char) byteRead);

                    buffer.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Matcher m = p.matcher(builder.toString());


                if (m.find()) {

                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(m.group(0)).getContent());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    Log.d("MIMIS_MATCHER", selectedRssItem.getDescription().toString());
                 };

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }
    }.start();
    }

private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    //@SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        mSpinner.clearAnimation();
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
        myimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        if (bitmap==null){

            myimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.aris_no_image);

        };
        }       
        };
```

because at the site there is also a jpg which has this XL

These are all the .jpg at the given page .

href="/media/k2/items/cache/df95c3d9029788dcdb6f520e9151056c_XL.jpg"

/media/k2/items/cache/df95c3d9029788dcdb6f520e9151056c_L.jpg"

"/images/stories/atnea2.jpg"

/images/stories/diarkeias-bc.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.sample_XL.jpg";
String regex = "[0-9a-zA-Z\\-\\._/:]*[XL]\\.jpg$";
System.out.println(url.matches(regex)); //this will be print true if case matches files ends with *XL.jpg and *X.jpg and *L.jpg.
```

You only want to check the string ends with '.jpg' use the regex

**String regex = "[\\x20-\\x7E]*\\.jpg$";**

If u want to find the exact match for file ends with *XL.jpg

String url = "http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items/cache.sample_XL.jpg";
  
**String regex = "[0-9a-zA-Z\\-\\._/:]*XL\\.jpg$";**
  
System.out.println(url.matches(regex)); //this will be print true if case matches

**If any space or special character along with 0-9a-zA-Z character  coming in your URL string please use the regex.(this will return true any string that ends with *XL.jpg)**

 String url = "http://planetaris.gr/media/k2/items %!@#$%/cache.sample_ssXL.jpg";

**String regex = "[\\x20-\\x7E]*XL\\.jpg$";**

Answer (score 0):

this regex: `/(media|images)/[^\.]*\.jpg`

matches all your samples:

href="/media/k2/items/cache/df95c3d9029788dcdb6f520e9151056c_XL.jpg"
/media/k2/items/cache/df95c3d9029788dcdb6f520e9151056c_L.jpg"
"/images/stories/atnea2.jpg"
/images/stories/diarkeias-bc.jpg"

Comment: ok I solve it.I used this Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/media/k2/items/cache.*\\XL.jpg"); and becuase the sample was not starting with http://..... I use a string local variable that uses the standard http://planetaris.gr/ and put the matcher string .................String imglink = "http://planetaris.gr"+ partiallink;